# How to disable same time selection in jquery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html

I am using jquery calendar to display the time as shown below:

```
<script>
$('.datepick').datetimepicker({
    datepicker:false,
    format:'H:i',
    step:15
});
</script>
```

Now, I don't want to repeat the time, like if I have already selected 10:00 from the time dropdown, then I should not be able to select the time again. i.e. unique time should be present.

As I am handling this using Java MAP in the backend JavaCode, the 'time' is getting overridden. 
I tried lot other things, but unable to resolve this. Please help me out.

Comment: pls show what you have tried

Comment: you will need some ajax with your datetimepiker

Comment: @madalinivascu isn't der any javascript validation that we can add?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the date after you select using a bootstrap disabled class.

```
$( ".datepick" ).change(function() {
   $( '#yorudatepickerid' ).addClass('disabled');
});
```